# Apache Freemarker - How to use Java code to compare value of a parameter

Tags: java, json, freemarker

I have a json template as below

```
{
    "Account_Number" : "${accNo}"
}
```

I want to use a user-defined directive which is basically a Java code  to check if accNo is greater than 0. If not, I want to set the value as 0000.

I was reading here ( https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html) that it is possible to write Java code by implementing the TemplateDirectiveModel interface. However, I was unable to retrieve the value of accNo.

Is it possible to achieve the above using user-defined directive? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like `<@accNoJson value=accNo />`, then you can get it from `params` parameter of `TemplateDirectiveModel.execute`. If you want something like `<@accNoJson/>` (which is a bit odd), then you can get it with `env.getVariable("accNo")`, where `env` is the 1st parameter of `TemplateDirectiveModel.execute`.

The most typical approach would be `${accNoJson(accNo)}`, in which case you should implement `TemplateMethodModelEx`.